# Tag <manifest> attribute package has invalid character '; '

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

I have an error inside Manifest.xml, how can i fix it? My error in instant-run is the following :

```
Tag <manifest> attribute package has invalid character '; '
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yavuzoktay.challenge.challenge;"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.11" >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:name="com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Mobile Challenge"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.yavuzoktay.challenge.MainActivity"
            android:label="Mobile Challenge" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.yavuzoktay.challenge.AlbumActivity"
            android:label="Album"
            android:parentActivityName="com.yavuzoktay.challenge.MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My error:
[image]

Your advice is important for me!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your screenshot is showing the wrong file. You need to edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in your `main` sourceset, which is probably the other tab.

Comment: I understand but i cant do it . how can i fix ?

Comment: @CommonsWare Nice 'gotcha'.

Comment: Assuming that this is a normal Android Studio project, open `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. This is **not** the file that is shown in your screenshot above. In `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, modify your `package` attribute in the `<manifest>` element to remove the `;`.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat self-explanatory ...

```
package="com.yavuzoktay.challenge.challenge;"
```

should be

```
package="com.yavuzoktay.challenge.challenge"
```

Remove the semicolon.

**EDIT:** Do this in the file `main/AndroidManifest.xml` and for every `AndroidManifest.xml` that you might have for build flavors like `debug/AndroidManifest.xml`. Leave all `AndroidManifest.xml` files alone that are under the `build` folder. Those are automatically generated and shouldn't be edited.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

modify for your tag package to

> package="com.yavuzoktay.challenge.challenge"